# Slack Record Owner Salesforce Flow

Tags: salesforce, slack, salesforce-lightning

Is there a way with the native Slack Salesforce integration to slack individual users?

From what I can tell you would have to have individual users added via the slack setup in Salesforce, then create a CTMD for each user, then call that CMTD in a flow to determine the correct destination ID. This would be fine if you only have like 5-10 users, but what about an org with 500?!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to:

Under the slack integration set the "Message Destination Name" as the user's full name that you are adding

In your flow call the slack destination object where Name = record owner name (or whatever lookup you want to use)

From the Message Destination object save the ID as var (I just find this easier)

Then in your slack action use the var and record ID